# Pandas Dataframe - record number of rows based on cumulative sum on a column with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, cumsum

In below df I already have column "A". I'm trying to add another column "Desired" where the value is the number of rows below the corresponding A's value, to first satisfy: cumulative sum of A's value >= 8

For example: row 1 of column "Desired" would be 3 because 5+2+3 >= 8.  rows 2 of column "Desired" would be 4 because 2+3+2+2>=8

Therefore the ideal new df would be like below.

df:

| A | Desired |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 8 | NA |
| 6 | NA |

Comment: can you make the df more readable?

Comment: what about now?

Comment: yeah it looks good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cumsum()` and a for loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[8,5,2,3,2,2,1,11,8,6]})
cumsum_arr = df['A'].cumsum().values
desired = np.zeros(len(df))
for i in range(len(df)):
    desired[i] = np.argmax((cumsum_arr[i:] - cumsum_arr[i])>=8)
df['desrired'] = desired
df['desrired'] = df['desrired'].replace(0, np.nan)
```

```
    A   desrired
0   8   3.0
1   5   4.0
2   2   4.0
3   3   4.0
4   2   3.0
5   2   2.0
6   1   1.0
7   11  1.0
8   8   NaN
9   6   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rolling()` window it can be achieved without any looping.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""|A|Desired|
|8  |3   |
|5  |4   |
|2  |4   |
|3  |4   |
|2  |3   |
|2  |2   |
|1  |1   |
|11 |1   |
|8  |NA   |
|6  |NA   |"""),sep="|")
df = df.drop(columns=[c for c in df.columns if "Unnamed" in c])
df["Desired"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Desired"], errors="coerce").astype("Int64")

# https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html see example
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=len(df))
df["DesiredCalc"] = (df["A"]
                     # looking at rows after current row
                     .shift(-1)
                     .rolling(indexer, min_periods=1)
                     # if any result of cumsum()>=8 then return zero based index + 1,  else no result
                     .apply(lambda x: np.where(np.cumsum(x).ge(8).any(), np.argmax(np.cumsum(x).ge(8)) + 1, np.nan))
                     .astype("Int64")
                    )
```

### output

```
 A  Desired  DesiredCalc
 8        3            3
 5        4            4
 2        4            4
 3        4            4
 2        3            3
 2        2            2
 1        1            1
11        1            1
 8     <NA>         <NA>
 6     <NA>         <NA>
```

Comment: anyway the run time can be shortened?

Comment: possibly replace `lambda` function with an actual function as `np.cumsum(x).ge(8)` is calculated twice

Comment: @ZLi agreed,  but with less context switching and marshalling between python & C layers